# What would the runtime be if I used binary search and then linear search on a sorted array?

Tags: performance, search

So for example I have this sorted array of `x` amount of Key, Value pairs(tuples). I have a method called `range` which takes 2 arguments, the first is the first key to find and the second is the last key to find. This function returns all of the keys between the two. So `range` uses binary search to find the first element and once it does, it uses linear search to go until the last key has been found. I thought this entire thing would have a runtime of O(log(n)) but now I am second guessing myself as it takes longer to execute than I'd like. So my question is what would be the runtime of this function since I seem to be mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

worst-case complexity - [**O(log(n))+O(n) = O(n)**]

just think of a case where first key is index-1 and second one is index-n in worst case scenario.

Comment: If I broke the continuous sorted array up into arrays of size 10 lets say, would it change the runtime?

Comment: No. it won't change. you are returning all keys between left and right. So, best complexity comes up with O(n) always. @JohnRon